# Oracle - Control file (if column length > 3, load data in other table)

Tags: oracle

I have a incoming file having data of 4 columns (ROLL, NAME, SCHOOL, LOCATION) terminated by "|" and wants to load the data into table "TABLE1" (having column names ROLL, NAME, SCHOOL, LOCATION).

I will be loading the data into the table TABLE1 using control file.

Example of data present in incoming file(fixed length file):

```
100SAMDPS  AUSTRIA
101JAMLPS  ANDORRA
102TOMMAPSADENMARK
103LAMCAPSTGERMANY
104KIMABS  FINLAND
```

I have created a table TABLE1

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (ROLL VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL, 
                     NAME VARCHAR2(3), 
                     SCHOOL VARCHAR2(3), 
                     LOCATION VARCHAR2(7) );
```

In above data present in incoming file, we see 2 records having SCHOOL column length greater than 3 and table described has SCHOOL column data length of max '3'.

So I have written the control file in this way:

```
LOAD DATA APPEND
INTO TABLE TABLE1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
     ROLL      POSITION(1:3)     CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:ROLL),' ')" ,
     NAME      POSITION(4:6)     CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:NAME),' ')" ,
     SCHOOL    POSITION(7:11)    CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:SCHOOL),' ')" ,
     LOCATION  POSITION(12:18)   CHAR "NVL(TRIM(:LOCATION),' ')" 
)
```

I don't want to increase the SCHOOL column length in TABLE1, instead I want to load the data whose SCHOOL column length > 3 in other table " TABLE2" having almost same structure as TABLE1 but SCHOOL column length of 10 (SCHOOL column length <=3 will be loading into TABLE1 else will be loading into TABLE2...How do I write the code in control file itself.

Result

```
  TABLE1 

 ROLL      NAME     SCHOOL      LOCATION
----------------------------------------------
 100       SAM       DPS        AUSTRIA
 101       JAM       LPS        ANDORRA
 104       KIM       ABS        FINLAND

 TABLE2

 ROLL      NAME     SCHOOL      LOCATION
----------------------------------------------
 102       TOM       MAPSA       DENMARK
 103       LAM       CAPST       GERMANY
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a second table with the same structure as the first, but with a different column length?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, SQL*Loader can't do that.

`WHEN` clause is what naturally comes in mind, but it accepts only full field name (or position) on the left side of the operator (which can only be `=` or `<>`). So, no functions allowed, while e.g. `length(school) > 3` is what we need.

So, what to do?

- load everything into `table2` which accepts long school names

  - then insert short school rows into `table1` and delete them from `table2`
- use **external tables** feature as it lets you access the input file as if it were an ordinary Oracle table so you'd easily insert "short" rows into `table1` and "long" ones into `table2`

  - drawback? Input data file has to reside in a directory on a database server; there must be a *directory*, Oracle object, which points to that filesystem directory, and you have to have access to it - talk to your DBA